# Using the FlashDevelop debugger with .fla, Actionscript 2, and Flash Professional 5.5

Tags: flash, debugging, actionscript, flash-cs5, flashdevelop

I have a flash project that consists of a .fla and a number of associated AS2 code files.

I'm new to Actionscript and Flash development in general but I'm trying to ramp up and setup a convenient development environment for working on this project.

I don't have full control to modify the basic project, I am just coming in and making adjustments/additions to the existing code and assets, mainly the code.

What is currently happening when I build the project using the Test Project button in FlashDevelop is that the project builds through Adobe Creative Suite Flash Professional 5.5 [CS5.5], it says Exporting Swf Movie while it builds, and then launches the swf file in a flash player window. Output is printed to the CS5.5 output window and my FlashDevelop debugger is not attached.

What I would like to happen is when I hit Test Movie (in the FlashDevelop debug configuration) the CS5.5 IDE will build the project but then when the Swf launches in the flash player, the FlashDevelop debugger will attach and I will get output and breakpoints in FlashDevelop.

Is something like this feasible? What steps would I need to take to configure CS5.5 and FlashDevelop this way if this isn't the default behaviour. If it should be the default behaviour, then what could be causing it to act as described above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FlashDevelop can't do interactive AS2 debugging. All you can do is using 'trace(value)' in your code to log messages which can then be monitored by FlashDevelop's Log Viewer:
http://www.ilike2flash.com/2012/03/flashdevelop-not-displaying-trace.html

Adobe Flash Pro is the only environment featuring an AS2 debugger:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flash/cs/using/WS3e7c64e37a1d85e1e229110db38dec34-7fc2a.html

Comment: Ok, thanks for clearing that up. Sorry for not marking the answer sooner, apparently my notifcation settings on stackoverflow aren't getting notifications of responses sent to me correctly.

I managed to make do just using traces rather than interactive debugging. Not really a fan of the Flash Pro debugger.